# Cordova Local notifications plugin not working after a while

Tags: angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins

I'm working on my 2nd app and having some problems implementing notifications.
It works when app in the foreground, and about 5 min after I put it to the background, even when the app is closed.

So the app listens for a firebase change and then launches;
cordova.plugins.notification.local.schedule

If the app doesn't respond after a while, I open it and it gives me the notifications

I used cordova.plugins.backgroundMode.enable(); to make the app run in the background, but no luck.

Any ideas or is there a better way to push notifications to your app?

Comment: As I known and used before, Cordova notification plug-in only works when app in pause (press Home button). If you press Back button, finish app by recent app, this plugin will not work. I think you could create new push notification plug-in: http://red-folder.blogspot.com/2012/09/phonegap-service-tutorial-part-1.html

Comment: It is in the background, with the home button, I found out that the delay is caused with sheduling the notification, the app gets information, the notification gets sheduled, but triggers a couple minutes later, not NOW as intended.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For everybody still searching, You have to capsulate the code in a device.ready(), if not you'll run into this bug